# How to create a ones of specific shape in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to create a ones of shape (200,240,2).
For an example, in numpy I can do:

```
r = numpy.ones_like(x) # x shape is (200,240,2)
r[...,0] = 0
r[...,1] = 1.57
```

How can I do it in tensorflow?

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: To create a tensor you can use either [`tf.zeros`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros) if you know the shape, or [`tf.zeros_like`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros_like).

Comment: @ygorg Yeah but I need to assign the values to last dimensions as described in the question. Since tensorflow does not allow element assign apart from variables. I need to know whether is there any way to achieve above thing?

Comment: Would your question be : How to assign single value to a tensorflow Tensor ? I think I do not quite understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question. Could you pleas check the question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do indexing and assignment at the same time in tensorflow, but otherwise, you can do the same things than in numpy. Here's one way to replicate your numpy code:

```
x_shape = x.shape
r0 = tf.zeros(x_shape[:-1])
r1 = tf.ones(x_shape[:-1]) + 0.57
r = tf.stack([r0,r1],axis=-1)
```

If you need other values than one or zero, you can do simple arithmetic:

```
r1 = tf.zeros(x_shape[:-1]) + 1.57
```